# How to close app in splash screenn in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I want my app should be close on splash screen. Actually the whole scenario is from server side if app is blacklisted then app should not open complete, it open show splash screen and show dialog that "you are not authorized " then on click of ok button app should close.. It is not working.. on splash screen why? It is working on Main Activity only

Comment: Without source codes you question is hard to answer.

Comment: Use `finish()` on your splashscreen. Do not start your `MainActivity`

Comment: @VenomVendor is saying right. 
if(authorized){
 // start main activity
 // finish splash activity
}else{
 // finish splash activity
}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use `SharedPreferences` and save the state like a `boolean isAuthorized` set it to `true` then in your SplashActivity do the following:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);

boolean isAuthorized = prefs.getBoolean("isAuthorized", false);

if(isAuthorized)
{
  startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class))
}
else
{
  finish(); // or show a dialog that prompts user that you are not authorized....
}
```

If you have never used `SharedPreferences` follow this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/).

Hope this will help you.